# Which process is occupying a certain pseudo terminal pts/X?

Tags: linux, terminal, open-files, pty

On Linux: Normally pseudo terminals are allocated one after the other.

Today I realized that even after a reboot of my laptop the first opened 
terminal window (which was always `pts/0` earlier) suddenly became `pts/5`.

This was weird and made me curious.  I wanted to find out which process is occupying the device `/dev/pts/0` and had no luck using common tools like `who` and `lsof` or even `ps` as suggested in the comment:

```
pf@pfmaster-P170EM:pts/6 /var/log 1115> ps auxww | grep pts/0 
pf        7042  0.0  0.0  17208   964 pts/6    S+   12:32   0:00 grep --color=auto pts/0
```

What I'm missing here?  Possibly infected by a rookit?

Comment: What's the output of `ps auxww|grep pts/0`?  (Edit it into your question, please!)

Comment: My session is also on a pts other than `pts/0`.  In my case, the other pts entries are from dead processes; see the output of `who -a`.

Comment: @jonasmalacofilho: Many thanks for having a look into this. In my case (running Kubuntu 14.04.3 LTS based on Debian jessie/sid) it remains mysterious to me, which process occupies pts/0.  It is not listed in the output oft the command ``who -a``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have [fuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)) installed and have the permission to use sudo:

```
for i in $(sudo fuser /dev/pts/0); do
    ps -o pid= -o command= -p $i
done
```

eg:

```
24622 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/terminator
24633 ksh93 -o vi
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an although very ugly way to figure out which process occupies the pseudo terminal `pts/0`.

As Superuser I did `cd /proc` and entered the following bash command:

```
for pid in [0-9]* ; do  \
    RES=`ls -l $pid/fd/* 2>/dev/null| grep pts/0`; \
    if [ -n "$RES" ]; then echo "Process $pid owns: $RES"; fi; \
done
```

This way I figured out that in my case the `pts/0` was occupied by the process `/usr/sbin/bumblebeed`.